# Modifying an entry by Channel Form throwing a PHP error : Call to a member function head_link()

Tags: safecracker, error

I have a very simple Channel Form on my page :

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="accueil" limit="1"}
    {exp:channel:form channel="accueil" entry_id="{entry_id}" require_entry="yes" return="accueil/index" error_handling="inline" show_fields="titre_de_laccueil|texte_de_laccueil|domaines_dexpertise"}
        {custom_fields}
            <p>
            <label for="{field_name}">{field_label}{if required}<span class="required_field_asterisk"> *</span>{/if}</label>
            {field_instructions}
            {formatting_buttons}

            {if error}
                <p class="error">{error}</p>
            {/if}

            {if textarea}
                <textarea id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" dir="{text_direction}" rows="{rows}">{field_data}</textarea>
            {/if}

            {if text}
                <input type="text" dir="{text_direction}" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" value="{field_data}" maxlength="{maxlength}" size="50">
            {/if}

            {if select}
                <select id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}">
                  {options}<option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>{/options}
                </select>
            {/if}

            {if checkbox}
                {options}
                  <label class="checkbox">{option_value}
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
                  </label>
                {/options}
            {/if}

            {if grid}
                {display_field}
            {/if}

            {if wygwam}
                {display_field}
            {/if}

            {if field_name=='domaines'}
                {display_field}
            {/if}

            </p>
        {/custom_fields}

  <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer les modifications">
{/exp:channel:form}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I just change the contents of the fields and click on submit --> no problem, it saves the modified entry as intended.

If I empty a required field and click on submit --> I get this error (that prevent the modified entry to be saved) instead of the validation :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: EE::$view
>
> Filename: libraries/File_field.php
>
> Line Number: 718
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function head_link() on a non-object in
>   [...]/system/expressionengine/libraries/File_field.php on line 718

I don't even have a file field in this channel!

I didn't find the reason of this...

EE version : 2.11.1

Comment: Some new investigations showed me that if I remove the 
{if wygwam}
            {display_field}
        {/if}
(I have a wygwam field in my channel) and empty a required field as explained above, it gives me the right validation message "This field is required" in place of throwing the PHP error...Perhaps this is a clue

Answer (score 0):

Try not wrapping the channel:form in a channel:entries tag. You shouldn't have to.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it doesn't change anything...